# python-docx library - How to extend the class "Document'

Tags: python, python-docx

In python-docx library, Document object is created using the constructor func:`docx.Document` which is in the file docx.api

```
def Document(docx=None):
"""
Return a |Document| object loaded from *docx*, where *docx* can be
either a path to a ``.docx`` file (a string) or a file-like object. If
*docx* is missing or ``None``, the built-in default document "template"
is loaded.
"""
docx = _default_docx_path() if docx is None else docx
document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
if document_part.content_type != CT.WML_DOCUMENT_MAIN:
    tmpl = "file '%s' is not a Word file, content type is '%s'"
    raise ValueError(tmpl % (docx, document_part.content_type))
return document_part.document
```

But the methods which can be applied to the object are located in the file docx.document.Document. Below is the snapshot

class Document(ElementProxy):
"""WordprocessingML (WML) document.

```
Not intended to be constructed directly. Use :func:`docx.Document` to open or create
a document.
"""

__slots__ = ('_part', '__body')

def __init__(self, element, part):
    super(Document, self).__init__(element)
    self._part = part
    self.__body = None

def add_heading(self, text="", level=1):
    """Return a heading paragraph newly added to the end of the document.

    The heading paragraph will contain *text* and have its paragraph style
    determined by *level*. If *level* is 0, the style is set to `Title`. If *level*
    is 1 (or omitted), `Heading 1` is used. Otherwise the style is set to `Heading
    {level}`. Raises |ValueError| if *level* is outside the range 0-9.
    """
    if not 0 <= level <= 9:
        raise ValueError("level must be in range 0-9, got %d" % level)
    style = "Title" if level == 0 else "Heading %d" % level
    return self.add_paragraph(text, style)

def add_page_break(self):
    """Return newly |Paragraph| object containing only a page break."""
    paragraph = self.add_paragraph()
    paragraph.add_run().add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
    return paragraph

def add_paragraph(self, text='', style=None):
    """
    Return a paragraph newly added to the end of the document, populated
    with *text* and having paragraph style *style*. *text* can contain
    tab (``\\t``) characters, which are converted to the appropriate XML
    form for a tab. *text* can also include newline (``\\n``) or carriage
    return (``\\r``) characters, each of which is converted to a line
    break.
    """
    return self._body.add_paragraph(text, style)
```

I want to understand - How can I use the methods of the class Document on the object created by the function - `docx.Document` . What is connecting both of them?

Also, how do I extend the class Document with a new method and apply the same on the object created by function. For example - below does not work

```
from docx.document import Document as doc1
class doc_new(doc1):
    def new_prop(self, q):
        self.name = q
        return self.name

document = Document()
x = document.new_prop("John")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Document` object returned by the `docx.Document()` function is created in the `.document()` method of `docx.parts.document.DocumentPart` here:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/parts/document.py#L47-L52

So it is created like any other `Document` object, by calling the class with the document's main XML element.

Since that object is a `Document` instance, it has all the methods and properties defined on the `docx.document.Document` class.

The construction of that `Document` object is less direct because that makes the API easy to use in the majority of cases. If it were direct, users would have to dig out the XML element for themselves and a lot of things would become much more complicated than they need to be for 99.9% of users.

As far as extending the functionality of `Document` you have three main choices I can see:

1. Create a fork of `python-pptx` and edit the `docx.document.Document` class to suit, along with any subordinate classes like `Paragraph` etc.
2. "Wrap" (aka. *Compose*) a document object with your own object that adds its own functionality and passes through other calls to the underlying document object.

   There are a lot of reasons to prefer this second approach over the first, mostly that it is a lot less work. The same composition strategy can work for lower-level objects like paragraphs.
3. Write functions that take a document as their first argument and do what you want. This is kind of like a "disembodied" method of the `Document` object. All `Document` methods are functions that take a `Document` object as the first parameter (`self`) so you can do most of what a method can do in this way.

   This is the simplest approach by far, the way most folks do it, and the method I recommend (and use myself).

Comment: Thanks . But how do you come to know that the document object is created by the docx.parts.document.DocumentPart . I am not able to find this from the below function.

Comment: `document_part` is a `DocumentPart` object obtained from `Package.open`. If you inspect `DocumentPart.document` you'll see it calls the `docx.document.Document` constructor with the root XML element of the document it received from `Package.open()` when it was constructed.

Comment: @scanny how do you do option 2? I've tried defining a class with docx.document, docx.document.Document, etc., but none allow me to do self.add_paragraph within a method.

Comment: @StevenBrown if you create a separate question and include the code you tried that isn't working I'll take a look. Make sure to tag it with the `python-docx` tag and I'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks . But how do you come to know that the document object is created by the docx.parts.document.DocumentPart . I am not able to find this from the below function.

```
'''
def Document(docx=None):
"""
Return a |Document| object loaded from *docx*, where *docx* can be
either a path to a ``.docx`` file (a string) or a file-like object. If
*docx* is missing or ``None``, the built-in default document "template"
is loaded.
"""
docx = _default_docx_path() if docx is None else docx
document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
if document_part.content_type != CT.WML_DOCUMENT_MAIN:
    tmpl = "file '%s' is not a Word file, content type is '%s'"
    raise ValueError(tmpl % (docx, document_part.content_type))
return document_part.document

'''
```

Comment: Your response should be in a comment on my answer, not a separate answer. I understand the comment space is limited, but answers are for, well, answers :)